# Java FlowLayout - Margin/padding of specific elements?

Tags: java, swing, padding, layout-manager, gaps-in-visuals

I am very new to Swing, and I'm trying to make a GUI.
Using Netbeans' GUI creator thing, I managed to make something I liked. But it makes me feel bad that I used the editor for this, so now I am trying to make the same design using code.
Here is a picture of what I am trying to make:
[image: what I want to make]
Right now I am just focusing on creating the "Criteria" section (yes I know I spelled it wrong in the picture)
Here is what I currently have so far:
[image: what I currently have]
I've highlighted in red where I want to increase the margin:

- Between the right of the text boxes and left of the labels
- Between the top of the Criteria panel and the JFrame
- Between the left and right sides of the panel and the JFrame

I come from web development where increasing the margins is what I want to do. If this is incorrect terminology, please inform me.
Here is the code I am currently using:

```
public class Criteria extends JPanel {
    JLabel JobLabel = new JLabel();
    JLabel BoxLabel = new JLabel();
    JLabel PartLabel = new JLabel();
    JTextField JobInput = new JTextField();
    JTextField BoxInput = new JTextField();
    JTextField PartInput = new JTextField();

    public Criteria() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Criteria"));
        JobLabel.setText("Job");
        JobLabel.setLabelFor(JobInput);
        BoxLabel.setText("Box");
        BoxLabel.setLabelFor(BoxInput);
        PartLabel.setText("Part");
        PartLabel.setLabelFor(PartInput);
        JobInput.setColumns(8);
        BoxInput.setColumns(8);
        PartInput.setColumns(8);
        add(JobLabel);
        add(JobInput);
        add(BoxLabel);
        add(BoxInput);
        add(PartLabel);
        add(PartInput);
    }
}
```

I don't know how I would add margin to these components, so help would be very much appreciated. If I cannot achieve this effect with FlowLayout, then please tell me what I should use instead.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Swing tends to call margins or borders 'gaps'. The `FlowLayout` class (along with a few other layout classes) allows you to set the horizontal and vertical gaps [in its constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html#FlowLayout%28int,%20int,%20int%29), like so:

```
private static final int PADDING = 3;   // for example
...
    setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING, PADDING, PADDING));
```

This would add padding between the labels and their text boxes, however, but you could wrap each pair in a `JPanel` (probably with a `FlowLayout`). I would make a custom component class for this.

Comment: I heard of that, however I would only like to change the gaps between certain elements. For example, I want to keep the current gap between "Job" and the first box, but extend the gap between the first box and "Box." (however that does help with the gaps between the JPanel and Frame, so thank you)

Comment: Ah. I'm not aware of any way to do it selectively, but you could wrap each caption and text box in their own JPanel. What I would do is to create a custom component (extending JPanel) that contains the caption and text box in some sort of layout (probably a FlowLayout) and then add those to your main FlowLayout panel.

Comment: That works excellently. You should update your answer to include that, then I will mark it as accepted. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 8):

You should look into using an EmptyBorder to give your components "padding". You can create compound borders or can nest JPanels if you need more than one type of border around a JPanel or other component. For gaps between components, you can use the FlowLayout settings as noted above, or can use a strut from the Box class.